# A list of indices to extract observations from a list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, data-manipulation

I have a list of indices that I want to use to extract observations from a list of data frames. A simplified example is as follows:

```
#A list of indices used to extract observations based on the time column from the `dat` dataset
time.index <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(2,3,4))
#A list of data frames in which observations will be extracted based on the time column 
dat <- list(case1=data.frame(time=1:10, y=rnorm(10)), case2=data.frame(time=1:10, y=rnorm(10)), case3=data.frame(time=1:10, y=rnorm(10)))
#The expected result will be like this:
$case1
   time          y
1     1 -0.8954070
2     2  0.0270242
3     3 -0.4256890

$case2
   time       y
4     4  1.5789
5     5 -0.6692
6     6 -2.3306

$case3
   time       y
2     2 -0.7371
3     3 -0.3271
4     4  0.4128
```

Anyone knows how to achieve that? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` :

```
Map(function(x, y) x[x$time %in% y, ], dat, time.index)

#$case1
#  time     y
#1    1  1.75
#2    2  1.13
#3    3 -1.45

#$case2
#  time     y
#4    4 2.212
#5    5 0.572
#6    6 0.149

#$case3
#  time       y
#2    2 -0.0377
#3    3 -0.1700
#4    4  0.8414
```

Similarly, using `purrr`'s `map2` :

```
purrr::map2(dat, time.index, ~.x[.x$time %in% .y, ])
```

Comment: Much nicer. I was thinking that this was probably a `Map` problem.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward way (if you can overlook the ugly bracketing) is the old-school, no-apply loop method.

```
res <- list()
for(ii in 1:length(time.index)){
  res[[ii]] <- dat[[ii]][dat[[ii]]$time %in% time.index[[ii]] ,]
}

res
[[1]]
  time           y
1    1 -0.05802713
2    2 -0.80779933
3    3 -1.77802107

[[2]]
  time          y
4    4  0.3990907
5    5 -1.5834484
6    6 -0.3626801

[[3]]
  time          y
2    2 -1.8585653
3    3  1.0591013
4    4  0.6903189
```

You an add the names in the loop or after, like this:

```
names(res) <- names(dat)
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any way faster though? Maybe use the *apply family? I have a much larger dataset and so it may be slow using for loops

Comment: Ronak Shah answered after I did - I like his answer, and it seems to avoid loops (depending how Map is implemented under the hood). Even if it takes as long, his answer will be easier to maintain in future, whereas mine is a bit hard to read and therefore easy to break.

Answer (score 2):

In base R, **lapply** does the job:

```
setNames(lapply( 1:length(time.index),
   function(x) dat[[x]][dat[[x]]$time %in% time.index[[x]],] ),
   names(dat) )
#$case1
#  time          y
#1    1  1.7458360
#2    2 -0.6945523
#3    3 -0.3699472

#$case2
#  time          y
#4    4  0.5407011
#5    5 -0.3895972
#6    6 -1.1165133

#$case3
#  time          y
#2    2 -0.8736470
#3    3  0.1831833
#4    4  1.0551148
```